# accessing element property from variable

Tags: javascript, variables, properties

I have got function:

```
this.addNode = function(element){

            var context = this.obj.element;
         return context;    
}
```

and this.obj is an object with some properties. How can I access to these properties when I wanna call them from variable like i.e above?

Comment: Question on how to access properties of object is just way too basic. Please consult JS reference manual instead.

Comment: **Your code doesn't seem right.** What are you trying to do?

Comment: i know how to access to propoerty, but when I try to access via variable name (like above - 'element' variable) the variable isnt sent to function and it is undefined.

Comment: this is only part of code, this.obj is a json object and I wanna call appropriate property to call from variable.

Answer (score 0):

I need to make a few assumptions since the example is not entirely clear. Let's say you have this code in a constructor and you want to reference `obj.<some-passed-name>` of this object, then you cannot use `.` but rather `[]` like this

```
function SomeObj() {

  this.obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };

  this.addNode = function (element) {
    var context = this.obj[element];
    return context;    
  }
}
```

and you can use it then like this

```
var o = new SomeObj();
o.addNode('a'); // returns 1
o.addNode('b'); // returns 2
```

but generally it is recommended to hide the implementation (that `obj` property) like this

```
function SomeObj() {

  var obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };

  this.addNode = function (element) {
    var context = obj[element]; // not using this.obj
    return context;    
  }
}
```

if you pass `obj` as a parameter to the constructor, it is even simpler:

```
function SomeObj(obj) {
  this.addNode = function (element) {
    var context = obj[element]; // not using this.obj
    return context;    
  }
}

var o = new SomeObj({ a: 1, b: 2 });
o.addNode('a'); // returns 1
o.addNode('b'); // returns 2
```

I hope I guessed the question right.